# Build path from nodejs request.url pathname

Tags: node.js

I want to get `/ok/ä.txt` from `/very///bad/%D0%B9/../../../../../request/../ok/%C3%A4.txt` in node.js. I discovered the following method:

```
var url = require('url'), path = require('path');
require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {

    var file = null;
    try {
        file = path.normalize(decodeURI(url.parse(request.url).pathname));
    } catch (e) {
    }

    console.log(file);
    response.end();
}).listen(3002, '127.0.0.1');
```

Does some better method exist, without the try/catch block?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just get rid of the `try..catch` block, because `path.normalize` and `decodeURI` never throw an error and `url.parse` only throws an error if the parameter is not of type `string`:

```
...
if (typeof url !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError("Parameter 'url' must be a string, not " + typeof url);
}
...
```

and since `request.url` is always of type `string` that won't happen either.